# qt waitforreadyread() inconsistent?

Tags: c++, qt

Under Qt 4.7.1, OS X 10.6.8
(have to use this -- later versions
of Qt and/or OS X introduce severe
incompatibilities for my users)

The following works. Sometimes. Then sometimes not.
When  it doesn't work, it returns "Unknown Error"

hst is good in all cases, qDebug returns same correct
data for hst every time.

The idea is, use ->get to pull a CGI URL; the CGI
returns some data, which I can ignore in this case.
Then I'm done.

hst is a well formed URL,

http://yadda.com/cgi-bin/whatever.py

```
QString hst;
QNetworkReply *qnr;
QNetworkAccessManager *qqnap = NULL;

qqnap = new(std::nothrow) QNetworkAccessManager(tmw);
if (qqnap != NULL)
{
    hst = loaduphst(); // get qstring to send
    qnr = qqnap->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(hst))); // report in and fetch update info
    if (qnr->waitForReadyRead(3000) == FALSE)
    {
        qDebug() << "waitForReadyRead() returned FALSE -- error or timeout:" << qnr->errorString();
    }
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "qqnap is NULL";
}
```

yadda.com is up; the target script is dead simple
and works fine from browser or cmd line every time.

This is running within the context of
MainWindow::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *ce)
before I emit ce->accept() GUI is still up,
etc.

Hints? Tips? Abuse? Thanks!

Comment: Blocking methods in the gui thread are a bad idea, and generally you're wasting a thread (an expensive resource) just to wait for a network host. Threads on OS X 10.6 are *really* expensive - stuff you can get away with on 10.9 just doesn't fly on 10.6. Use the signals and write it out asynchronously. You could take [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29544684/1329652) and port it to Qt 4, it'd be a straightforward thing to do.

Comment: My ASSumption was that "waitForReadyRead()  would not block; it'd just let the event  loop  idle without  events  until a signal  arrived, thereby returning control to the OS regularly.  I can't even say it  was a  bad assumption. the bad assumption was assuming it was implemented because the docs described how to use  it, lol. Anyway, yeah,  rewrote it  in a friendly manner, code is below. Thank you  for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More-or-less  synchronous use of async networking is  very problematic in the context of the main GUI loop. Signals that don't appear (finished OR readyRead), URLs that sometimes send and sometimes don't... and of course, as the kind person above pointed out, unimplemented functions. Zebras!

What we can do, though, is fire up an event loop and a timer on our own, and this will in a more-or-less friendly way act synchronous.

Perhaps some poor soul will need to poke a website CGI as I do; here's the code. It works. At least under Qt 4.7.1 it does!

So anyway, here it is:

```
QNetworkReply *qnr;
QNetworkAccessManager *qqnap;
QNetworkRequest qnwr;
QEventLoop w;
QTimer arf;

if ((qqnap = new(std::nothrow) QNetworkAccessManager(this)))
{
    qnwr.setUrl(myUrl());                                       // Build web goodness
    qnwr.setRawHeader("User-Agent", myUserAgent());

    arf.setSingleShot(true);

    if (connect(&arf,  SIGNAL(timeout()),                       // timer firing blows...
                &w,    SLOT(quit())                             // ...out event loop
       ) == FALSE)
       { return(BAD_CONNECT_TOUT); }

    if (connect(qqnap, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),        // notify we finished...
                this,  SLOT(qqnapReplyQ(QNetworkReply*))        // ...cuz I need to know
       ) == FALSE)
       { return(BAD_CONNECT_FINISHED_NOTIFY); }

    if (connect(qqnap, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),        // finishing blows out...
                   &w, SLOT(quit())                             // ...event loop
       ) == FALSE)
       { return(BAD_CONNECT_FINISHED_ELOOP); }

    if ((qnr = qqnap->get(qnwr)))                               // Go if qnr is good
    {
        arf.start(6000); // timeout in ms                       // Watchdog timer on
        w.exec();                                               // handle all that
        if (arf.isActive()) { arf.stop(); }                     // kill timer if needed
    }
    else { return(BAD_WWWGET); }                                // FAIL
}
else
{
    return(BAD_NWAM);                                            // FAIL
}
return(ZEN_NETWORKING);
```

Answer (score 2):

`waitForReadyRead` is not implemented in `QNetworkReply`. The [default implementation](https://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/7786d15e93723eccef0f379c96f994be87375450:src/corelib/io/qiodevice.cpp#L1536) does nothing:

```
bool QIODevice::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)
{
    Q_UNUSED(msecs);
    return false;
}
```

Use the [`readyRead`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal to find out when there is data available to be read.

Comment: ok, I tried using readyread. Also finished() from the network manager. Neither one gets hit. Ever. But the get() still works... sometimes. What's REALLY weird is that I do this near exit time,  and wait about ten seconds for it to complete... same code either way for me... but if I exit by Apple-Q, it seems to work the majority of the time. If I exit  by closewindow, it fails most of the time.  Should I add the code with the signals? Also, I'm doing this at the close of the app; it's reporting  in. Other than  waiting in a loop with sleep() for  the signal  elsewhere, anything I  should do?

Comment: @fyngyrz Sounds like you blocked the event loop so no signals ever got processed.