# Files getting corrupted when being downloaded using QNetworkAcessManager

Tags: qt, http, file-transfer, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm developing a client app whose purpose is to download some files from a web server, temporarily store them in the Temp folder, check for file integrity, then send them to a FTP server in a Embedded Linux device.

Recently I got problems when doing the process in a preliminary development stage when I was trying to do the download from my local machine (see related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29543601/executable-getting-somehow-corrupted-when-being-copied)). Now I'm able to download and upload without errors and with verification (I'm using QCryptographicHash + file size to check for any nonconformities) from my machine, but the same doesn't happen when I try downloading from the HTTP server.

There is a total of 8 files being downloaded: three .tar.gz, one simple text, two programs and two binaries. I'm able to successfully download all compressed files, the text file and one of the binaries, but the others, namely the two programs and one of the binaries (a Linux Kernel image) are always being incorrectly downloaded.

I check this by noticing not only that the hash returns error for them, but also for their sizes: their sizes are always wrong (and always the same erroneous value for any download attempt). And the files in the server are all correct.

My first suspicion was that I need to configure the HTTP download in a way that differs from the common FTP download from the local machine, but I'm unaware on how would that be. Moreover if this extra configuration was needed, then why some of the files always return correctly?

Here is the relevant code as for now:

```
void MainWindow::processNextDownload()
{
    QUrl ulrTemp(updateData.at(transferStep).downloadUrl.arg(ui->leID->text()));    //"//" +

    if (updateData.at(transferStep).downloadUrl.contains("http"))
        ulrTemp.setScheme("http");
    else
        ulrTemp.setScheme("file");

//    ulrTemp.setUserName();
//    ulrTemp.setPassword();
//    ulrTemp.setPort();

    qDebug() << "Downloading" << transferStep << "from" << ulrTemp;

#if 1
    poReply = downloadNetworkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(ulrTemp));
#else
    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(ulrTemp);
    request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.60 Safari/537.17");

    poReply = downloadNetworkManager->get(request);
#endif

    connect(poReply,SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)),this,SLOT(slotDownloadProgress(qint64,qint64)));

    ui->statusBar->showMessage(tr("Downloading: %1").arg(updateData.at(transferStep).itemName));
}


void MainWindow::slotFileDownloaded(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    if (reply && (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError))
    {
        ui->statusBar->clearMessage();

        if (!isSingleFile)
        {
            const QString strTemp = tr("An error occurred while downloading \"%1\": %2 (error message: %3)")
                                    .arg(updateData.at(transferStep).downloadName).arg(reply->error()).arg(reply->errorString());

            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error in download"),strTemp);
        }
        else
        {
            //irrelevant...
        }

        finished(false);

        return;
    }

    qDebug() << "To write: " << reply->bytesAvailable();

    QByteArray downloadedData = reply->readAll();

    reply->deleteLater();
    poReply->deleteLater();

    //![]
    static const QString tempFilePath = QDir::tempPath();

    if (!isSingleFile)
    {
        QFile file(tempFilePath + "/" + updateData.at(transferStep).downloadName);


        if (!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Truncate))
        {
            qDebug() << "Failure opening temp file to write: " << file.fileName();

            QMessageBox::critical(this,
                                  tr("Error"),
                                  tr("An error occured while trying to open a temporary file to write the downloaded data (file: %1).").arg(file.fileName()));

            transferStep = downloadStepCount;

            slotFileUploaded(NULL);

            return;
        }

        qint32 bytesWritten = file.write(downloadedData);
        file.flush();

        if (downloadedData.size() != bytesWritten)
            qDebug() << "Write failed, wrote" << bytesWritten << "out of" << downloadedData.size() << "bytes.";
        else
            qDebug() << "Wrote " << bytesWritten << "bytes.";


        file.close();

        //![]
        if (++transferStep >= downloadStepCount)
        {
            qDebug() << "Start hash check";
            slotStartHashCheck();

            return;
        }

        processNextDownload();
    }
    else
    {
        //irrelevant...
    }
}
```

And this is why I get (the last number value after the "=" in the hash code is the file size):

[image: Error message]

So what am I missing?

Comment: I don't see any immediate bug, `qint32 bytesWritten = file.write(downloadedData)` can write less than intended, but as you compare the sizes, you should see if it doesn't succeed... The sizes on disk match the ones in "Calculated...", I guess? Then the code calculating the hashes might also have bugs, but they should show regardless of local vs. http server... Downloading the files works by other means, I assume? Browser, wget etc. It would be also interesting to know if the downloaded file is a partial download (matching the expected file but truncated) or if it is  otherwise corrupted.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Hi! Yes, the file sizes calcualted by Linux Ubuntu matches the files in all situations: the originals with the original size (which appears in the expected hash code) and the downloaded with the wrong size (after "Calculated..."). So no bugs in the hash code calculator: I use the same functions in all places. Moreover even if the hash was wrong, the file size still has problems; I could check by it alone.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld About the browser, that was interesting: downloading with Mozilla Firefox I got the EXACT same situation! (the same files were right and the same were wrong). About it still being valid, that's worthless: even if the files are still working somehow, I need to check their quality this way or some other which doesn't include "execute and see" :)

Comment: Sure, but it would be valuable information to debug what's going wrong. But if mozilla fails the same way, the problem seems to be server-side?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld good call. I'm doing some research on the web and I'll be back later with some updates. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld it seems I found the problem: have a look at superuser.com/questions/925229/files-get-corrupted-when-downloaded-from-ftp-server . Now I need to learn how to configure QNetworkAcessManager to download in binary and the problem is finished.

Comment: It sounds weird that QNAM should need to adapted for this. Which content type is the server reporting?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld well actually it doesn't; my mistake. QNAM already downloads binaries; for some reason my initial testing with it failed, so I assumed it downloaded with ASCII. (But the server doesn't report anything; it is fine: I just have to guarantee that files were uploaded as binaries).